# temporary Hide or Disable Master Navigate menu

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

on master file got ...

```
<div id="nav-main">
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Orientation="Horizontal"
              Width="573px" CssClass="menu-main" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" 
              StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="StaticSelectedStyle" Height="32px" 
              StaticSubMenuIndent="18px" >
        <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="StaticSelectedStyle"></StaticSelectedStyle>
    </asp:Menu>
```

also got ...

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
```

and sitemap...

got code ...

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    } // sorry for formating XD
```

and ... I need to hide or disable then enable or show site menu (I mean visible content)

On my pages I'm making

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

also I'm not sure if that's a good way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [security trimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it up with a [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) control?

```
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
       Please log in for personalized information.
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
       <div id="nav-main">...</div>
    </LoggedInTemplate>
<asp:LoginView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write `Menu1.Visible = false;`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to hide/show menu base on user authenticated or not.

Menu1.Visible = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;